# How can i access the first table inside A Div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following markup inside my SharePoint webpage
:-

```
<div style="width:1000px; height:1000px;" allowdelete="false" class="noindex" id="WebPartWPQ2" haspers="false" webpartid="e016a540-49da-4220-b779-94f997f7e508">
    <table >//how to access this!!!
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="part1">
                        <div id="listFormToolBarTop" style="display: none;">
```

now i want to define a custom CSS file, and to be able to access the first `table` inside the `div` with id = `WebPartWPQ2` and to change the width of the `table` to be equal to the `div`'s current width?
Can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just

```
#WebPartWPQ2 > table:first-of-type {
    //some properties
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `:first-of-type` instead, in case he adds some element before the table.

Comment: @LcSalazar But wait, I didn't write just `:first-child`, I added `table:first-child`... So it will be anyway a table... Or I am misunderstanding something...

Comment: I mean using `table:first-of-type` instead of `table:first-child`, because otherwise you'd only target the table if it is the very first child of the container. Using the `first-of-type` targets the first occurence of a table element, regardless of its index.

Comment: To be exact, this works only when the `table` element is a child of the `div`. It would not work in the presence of some intervening markup (e.g. the `table` is a child of an inner `width`).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela so what i should use instead of this?

Comment: @john I answered your question. Jukka K. Korpela points another case.